# How do I link two rails apps databases and models together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

So I have an e-commerce site and I was tasked with linking my rails(4) app with another website(our manufacturing vendor) to show orders placed and to update inventory from their side. Aka I need to share a database and models between two rails apps. The vendor website is not built out just an FYI, I have to build it from scratch.

Side Note: I know a custom admin panel would be easier but, my boss, who doesnt know tech at all seems to be adamant on having these on separate URLs, even though he owns both companies, the one I work for and the manufacturing company.

I need just maybe a roadmap, or just a point in the right direction because I am not exactly sure what I am looking for. Just some solid information about how to do this.

I currently use heroku and AWS for my existing rails app.
I use PostgreSQL as my DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use [establish_connection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-establish_connection)

I've only done this sort of thing once so the below might be wrong but will hopefully give you an idea. Not sure what you mean by link the models.  But this would allow you to query the vendor db and have models you'd want to namespace that would relate to those databases.

I'd setup an entry in database.yml for the vendor database (probably one for each environment)

I would then have a base vendor model that all the others inherit from

```
class VendorApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "vendor_#{ Rails.env }"
end
```

Assuming you setup database.yml to have vendor_development e.t.c

Answer (score 2):

Sharing database is very easy. Actually, it's just the same as not sharing database. You just put appropriate configuration in the `database.yml` and declare models.

Now you might be thinking "hey, that's duplication of code! Why don't I just extract models in a gem or something?". To which I say, don't. Just duplicate what's necessary. It is very likely that in one app you'll need full-blown models, with validations, before/after_save hooks and whatnot. And the other app will only read data, so it doesn't need any of that extra complexity.